# How do I remove generated HTML around images in posts?

Tags: images, html

When I insert images into a blog post, wp is automatically inserted markup around the img element: specifically a div and a p (for the caption).....where is that markup being generated in wp sourcecode?

Answer (score 1):

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
   return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

The p tags come from [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: is filter_ptags_on_images your solution? i just put that in my functions.php? i don't see the function in wpautop. thanks for showing me where that is regardless....good to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look inside the media.php file in the wp-includes folder. In WP 3.4, around line 198. This is the function which generates the markup for images, and if I am not mistaken, you should be able to filter it in your functions.php file.